# Add virtual methods with parameters to as_json input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I got this model:

```
class Post
  def rating_by(ip_address, user = nil)
    if user
      ratings.where("ratings.user_id = ?", user.id).first
    else
      ratings.where("ratings.ip_address = ?", ip_address).first
    end
  end
end
```

As you might notice, I allow ratings by both users and visitors.

I'd like to output posts as json with an additional `user_rating` attribute.

This is my current controller:

```
@posts = Post.trending(10)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @posts.to_json  }
end
```

Of course this won't show it, but I'd like to know if there's a possibility of using `to_json`'s `:methods` option and specify parameters as well, something like:

```
@posts.to_json(extra: {user_rating: "rating_by(#{request.remote_ip}, #{@current_user.id})"})
```

So that I end up with something like:

```
[{ id: 54, title: "Foo", user_rating: 8 }]
```

Other suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Have a look at Active Model Serializers. You'll be able to add new compound attributes as well as "meta" attributes.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I commented on your question, but I thought I would add some detail.

From [Active Model Serializers' page](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) :

```
class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :first_name, :last_name, :full_name

  def full_name
    "#{object.first_name} #{object.last_name}"
  end
end
```

So you could define a `user_rating` parameter in your serializer.

Moreover, Active Model Serializers allows the use of a `meta`

```
render json: @posts, meta: {total: 10}
```

So you could simply computer `user_rating` and send it with `meta`.